# Perl swap command doesn't seem to work with output redirection

Tags: perl, unix, solaris

My input `foo.txt` is this:

```
Grull^Zn Hernand^Zz
```

where the ^Z resolves to the control character `\x1a` (verified with `od -x` on the file )

When I run the following Perl command:

```
perl -pe s/\x1a//g foo.txt
```

I get the output: `Grulln Hernandz`

as expected.  However when I redirect this to a file

```
perl -pe s/\x1a//g foo.txt > out.txt
```

The files are identical, demonstrated by

```
diff -c out.txt foo.txt
No differences encountered
```

How can I force this behavior to work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think

```
perl -pe s/\x1a//g foo.txt
```

does what you think it does. In any sane solaris shell, an unquoted `\x` is treated the same as `x`, and you are running the same thing as

```
perl -pe s/x1a//g foo.txt
```

You can test this by executing

```
echo s/\x1a//g
```

and see what gets passed to the shell. You can also try

```
perl -pe s/\x1a//g foo.txt | od -c
```

to see whether the control characters really are removed from your input.

The correct thing to do is to enclose your one-line script in single quotes:

```
perl -pe 's/\x1a//g' foo.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: So is this an instance of bash interpreting what it thinks the line should be before passing it into perl?  The single-quotes worked, and so did using `CTRL+V,Z`

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how you're are ascertaining that the first version works, but it doesn't for me.

You need to either escape the backslash in the regex, or quote it (quoting it is more common).

```sh
$ hexdump -C input
00000000  61 62 63 1a 64 65 66 1a  67 68 69 0a              |abc.def.ghi.|
$ perl -pe s/\x1a//g input | hexdump -C
00000000  61 62 63 1a 64 65 66 1a  67 68 69 0a              |abc.def.ghi.|
$ perl -pe s/\\x1a//g input | hexdump -C
00000000  61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68  69 0a                    |abcdefghi.|
$ perl -pe 's/\x1a//g' input | hexdump -C
00000000  61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68  69 0a                    |abcdefghi.|
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ultimately ended up doing (though I found out that mob's solution worked too) was instead of entering `\x1a` I pressed and held `Ctrl`, then `v, z`

This also has the benefit of being a little more readable.